# Django ModelForm failing to save

Tags: python, django

I've got a Django model as follows:

models.py

```
class Property(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    address_line1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address_line2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=0)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pin = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=20)
    secondary_number = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='dynamic/img')
    square_feet = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=200, default=0)
    price = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=200, default=0)
    NO = 'NO'
    YES = 'YES'
    APPROVAL = ((NO, 'no'), (YES, 'yes'))
    active = models.CharField(choices=APPROVAL, default=NO, max_length=3)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

A modelform for this:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter name for Property'}), required=True)
    desc = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter a small description', 'rows': '5', 'style': 'resize:none;'}), required=True)
    address_line1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter first line of address'}), required=True)
    address_line2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter second line of address'}), required=True)
    locality = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter locality'}), required=True)
    city = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter city name'}), required=True)
    state = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter state name'}), required=True)
    pin = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter pincode'}), required=True)
    phone = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter contact number'}), required=True)
    secondary_number = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter secondary contact number'}), required=False)
    image = forms.FileInput()
    square_feet = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter area of property in square feet'}), required=True)
    price = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter price of property in Rupees'}), required=True)
    NO = 'NO'
    YES = 'YES'
    APPROVAL = ((NO, 'no'), (YES, 'yes'))
    active = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=NO)

    class Meta:
        model = Property
```

and my views.py for this is as follows:

```
def postproperty(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('postthanks'))
        else:
            print form.errors

    else:
        form = PostForm()

    content = {'form': form}
    return render_to_response('postproperty.html', content, context)
```

the template contains this:

```
<form id="property_form" method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p style="color: red;">
            Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
        </p>
    {% endif %}
    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {{ field.help_text}}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Property" class="btn btn-info test-button" style="margin-top:20px;"/>
</form>
```

The form is rendered correctly in the template. When I go to save the form from the template, it gives me `Please correct the error below`. No error is specified and I'm lost as to which field seems to be giving me an error. 
Help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
As Daniel said, I added `{{ field.errors }}` and `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` to the template. It shows error in the image field. Why would this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to add this to the template:

`<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/foo/">`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're not showing any of the errors in the template. Along with each field and label, you should add `{{ field.errors }}`, plus `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` at the to of the form.

Comment: Doing that, gives me an error for the image field where it says Image field is required